# Inspiration of how to quote an e-mail correspondence

Tags: tcolorbox, typography, best-practices, quoting

I am looking for a good way to typeset a e-mail correspondence (maybe including multiple levels of quotations). In an e-mail program this may look like this:

[image]

this

[image]

or this one

[image]

I am not looking of how to reproduce those, but I am looking for a typographically professional and nice, maybe fancy looking way to do this in a printed letter.

So if you have encountered this problem in the past and you have a beautiful solution to this, it would be great if you could share it here.

This question seems to be a community wiki question (but this feature doesn't seem to exist anymore).

Comment: If it is not about the technical implementation the question might be better suited at https://ux.stackexchange.com or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ or maybe https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ or https://writing.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Marijn Thats true, I initially considered to post the question on graphicsdesign.stackexchange.com and implement the TeX part by myself. However I posted it here because of three reasons: 1. I hope that someone already solved that issue in latex; 2. In a solution one should have the abilities and limitations of LaTeX in mind and it should fit into the "typographic" philosophy of LaTeX; 3. In my experience on this site there are many contributors which have a very good eye for professionally looking printed documents.

Answer (score 3):

The second example (or at least something similar) is not too difficult with nested `tcolorboxes`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\tcbset{
    every box/.style={notitle, fontupper=\ttfamily, 
            sharp corners, boxrule=0pt, leftrule=.5mm, rightrule=.5mm},
    every box on layer 1/.style={every box, colback=white},
    every box on layer 2/.style={every box, colback=blue!10, colupper=blue!70!black, colframe=blue!70!black},
    every box on layer 3/.style={every box, colback=red!10, colupper=red!70!black, colframe=red!70!black},
    every box on layer 4/.style={every box, colback=green!10, colupper=green!70!black, colframe=green!70!black},    
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
Welcome to the Quote Colors site!
\begin{tcolorbox}
You can choose between three quoting modes as shown here.
\begin{tcolorbox}
So what's this?
\begin{tcolorbox}
Just a stupid example to demonstrate the options in Quote Colors\dots
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
Have fun!
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]