# Leave space for three logos on the title page

Tags: front-matter, variable, xcoffins

I am working on realizing a thesis template according to the requirements of my University. I would like to have the space for three logos in the title page, a big logo in the middle and two smaller on either side. However, to keep the template flexible enough, I would like to give the user the opportunity to use just one (or two) logos. I've implemented this in the following way

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \hfill
    \ifx \@smallLogoLeft \@empty
    \else
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{\@smallLogoLeft}
    \fi
    \hfill
    \ifx \@LogoCenter \@empty
    \else
    \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=3cm]{\@LogoCenter}
    \fi
    \hfill
    \ifx \@smallLogoRight \@empty
    \else
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{\@smallLogoRight}
    \fi
    \hfill
    
    \par
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE \@department \par}
    \vspace{2.5cm}
    {\huge\bfseries \@title \par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\Large\itshape \@author \par}
    \vfill
    \@titlepagesentence

    \vfill


    {\large \@submissiondate \par}
\end{titlepage}}
```

which I think it's a naive attempt to solve the problem. What would you people suggest in order to implement it more stable way?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over time, I found that the `xcoffin` package will solve all my problems of positioning things exactly where I wanted them.
This is very useful in cover design, thesis in particular, which often have very strict requirements.

The idea is simple: you put your contents in special boxes (coffins) that have handles and then you attach the coffin (\Join... ) using those handles and adding horizontal o vertical shifts if necessary. One coffin, I called Frame, of zero dimensions, serves as a collector for the others.

In this way if you comment a `Join` the coffin will disappear from the assembly without perturbing the others. The same thing will happen if you fill (`Set`) it with no content.
The `\csr` and `\crl`  do just that.

I defined a `\maketitlex`  with two optional parameters, the left and right logo, so there are 4 possible results, as the images show.

Please see my more complete  answer to a similar question:

[I need a rather complex layout for a scholarly edition and don't know where to start](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566593/i-need-a-rather-complex-layout-for-a-scholarly-edition-and-dont-know-where-to-s/566726#566726)

I added a chapter, headings, and some text to simulate a more realistic scenario.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %dummy text 
\usepackage{xcoffins}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % 
\fancypagestyle{empty}{}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rmfamily \small \nouppercase \leftmark}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
    
\NewCoffin\Frame
\NewCoffin\smallLogoLeft
\NewCoffin\smallLogoRight
\NewCoffin\smallLogoAbove
\NewCoffin\LogoCenter
\NewCoffin\departmentx
\NewCoffin\titlex
\NewCoffin\authorx

\usepackage{xparse}
    
\NewDocumentCommand{\maketitlex}{ O{} O{}  m }{%    
        \SetHorizontalCoffin\Frame{} % empty before reuse
        \csl{#1}%
        \csr{#2}%
        \SetHorizontalCoffin\LogoCenter{\includegraphics[width=150pt, height=50pt]{#3}} 
        \SetHorizontalCoffin\departmentx{\scshape\LARGE Department of lost objects} 
        \SetVerticalCoffin\titlex{\textwidth}{\Huge \sffamily \centering My most fantastic accomplishment \par so  far} 
        \SetHorizontalCoffin\authorx{\Large\itshape Just me}    
        \JoinCoffins\Frame[hc,vc]\LogoCenter[l,vc](100pt,0pt)
        \JoinCoffins*\Frame[\LogoCenter-r,\LogoCenter-vc]\smallLogoRight[l,vc](20pt,0pt)
        \JoinCoffins*\Frame[\LogoCenter-l,\LogoCenter-vc]\smallLogoLeft[r,vc](-20pt,0pt)    
        \JoinCoffins*\Frame[\LogoCenter-hc, \LogoCenter-b]\titlex[hc,vc](0pt,-100pt)
        \JoinCoffins*\Frame[\titlex-hc,\titlex-b]\authorx[hc,t](0pt, -40pt)
        \JoinCoffins*\Frame[\authorx-hc,\authorx-b]\departmentx[hc,t](0pt, -120pt)  
        \noindent\TypesetCoffin\Frame(0pt, -100pt)
        \cleardoublepage    
}
    

%%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127502/difference-between-if-and-ifx
        
\newcommand{\csr}[1]{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \SetHorizontalCoffin\smallLogoRight{}
    \else
        \SetHorizontalCoffin\smallLogoRight{\includegraphics[width=30pt]{#1}}%
    \fi
}       
        
\newcommand{\csl}[1]{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \SetHorizontalCoffin\smallLogoLeft{}
    \else
        \SetHorizontalCoffin\smallLogoLeft{\includegraphics[width=30pt]{#1}}
    \fi
}       

\begin{document}       

\pagestyle{empty}   

\maketitlex{example-image-A}    %only center

\maketitlex[example-image-B][]{example-image-A} %center + left

\maketitlex[][example-image-C]{example-image-A}  %center +right

\maketitlex[example-image-B][example-image-C]{example-image-A}  %all


\pagestyle{fancy} 
\chapter{Introduction}

\kant[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: A]
[image: BA]

[image: AC]
[image: ABC]