# Fixing my exercise frame

Tags: tcolorbox, mdframed

Firstly, My english is not good so if there is any mistake, please let me know.

I want to create a new environment in latex in order to make this frame
[image]
But when the text in frame is too long, there are some problems

[image]

Can you help me to solve my problems. Here is my code

```
\newcounter{vd}

\setcounter{vd}{0}

\newenvironment{vd}[1][]{
\def\ghichu{\textit{\color{blue}#1.}}
\addtocounter{vd}{1}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=10pt,fill=green!20] (vd)
\bgroup
\begin{minipage}{0.96\textwidth}
\textbf{\color{red}Ví dụ \thevd:}
}{
\flushright\ghichu

\end{minipage}

\egroup;

\draw[blue,line width=5pt] (vd.north west)--(vd.south west);

\end{tikzpicture}

}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a box using the tcolorbox package or any other? (image)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512501/create-a-box-using-the-tcolorbox-package-or-any-other-image)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a breakable `tcolorbox` instead of a `TiKZ` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{vd}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    sharp corners,
    colback=green!20,
    colframe=blue,
    boxrule=0pt,
    leftrule=2pt,
    detach title,
    coltitle=red,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title={Vi du~\thetcbcounter},
    before upper={\tcbtitle\quad}
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{vd}
\lipsum[1]
\end{vd}

\begin{vd}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{vd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am most grateful for your support. Thank you for taking the time to help me, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, i have a problem. I want to reset counter when i use \begin{vd} \end{vd}. Although i add \setcounter{vd}{0}, i can't do it. Can you help me?

Comment: @129492 When do you want reset the counter? After a section? Then insert `number within=section` beside `autocounter`. Please take a look at section "Initialization Option Keys" in `tcolorbox` documentation. By the way, the counter is not `vd` but `\tcbcounter`.

Comment: I want to reset the counter in different times so i decided to add "\setcounter{...}{0}". I added \setcounter{tcbcounter}{0} but it didn't change the number

Comment: i found the solution for my problems. I added  "\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand\showmycounter{\refstepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter}" 
and replace " title={Ví dụ~\thetcbcounter:}," to  title={Ví dụ~\showmycounter:},