# How do you balance two frame boxes in the same page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, boxes, flow-charts

I have a problem with fitting two flowcharts encased in frame boxes to fit nicely within a single page and how do you add a little more bottom space to the box frame?

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Schola}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

%% tikz
\tikzset{
  block/.style = {
    rectangle,
    draw,
    text width=5em,
    text centered,
    minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
    rounded corners,
  },
  line/.style = {
    draw,
    -latex',
  },
  text/.style = {textwidth = 3em
  },
    longblock/.style = {
    rectangle,
    draw,
    text width=10em,
    text centered,
    minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
    rounded corners,
    fill=white
  },
  }

%% personal commands
\newcommand{\mybox}[4]{
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=text,text width=\columnwidth-1.2cm, draw, rounded corners, line width=0.5pt, fill=#3, inner sep=1mm] (big) {\\#4};
        \node[draw, rounded corners, line width=.5pt, fill=#2, anchor=west, xshift=5mm] (small) at (big.north west) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
\mybox{QT nhân giống bằng nuôi cấy mô}{black!40}{black!10}{

\vspace{2ex}

\medskip
\hspace{5.5ex}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm, auto]
    \node [longblock] (bl1) {Chọn vật liệu nuôi cấy};
    \node [longblock, below of=bl1, node distance=1.75cm] (bl2) {Khử trùng};
    \node [longblock, below of=bl2, node distance=1.75cm] (bl3) {Tạo chồi};
    \node [longblock,below of=bl3, node distance=1.75cm]
    (bl4) {Tạo rễ};
    \node [longblock, below of=bl4, node distance=1.75cm]
    (bl5) {Cấy cây vào môi trường thích ứng};
    \node [longblock, below of=bl5, node distance=1.75cm] (bl6) {Trồng cây trong vườn ươm};
    
    \path [line] (bl1) -- (bl2);
    \path [line] (bl2) -- (bl3);
    \path [line] (bl3) -- (bl4);
    \path [line] (bl4) -- (bl5);
    \path [line] (bl5) -- (bl6);
    
\end{tikzpicture}

}


\vspace{-65.75ex}

\begin{flushright}
\mybox{Nhân giống bằng nuôi cấy mô ở cà rốt}{black!40}{black!10}{

\vspace{4ex}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\hspace{7ex}
    \node [longblock] (bl1) {Lát cắt ngang củ cà rốt};
    \node [longblock, below of=bl1, node distance=1.75cm] (bl2) {Các mẫu mô};
    \node [longblock, below of=bl2, node distance=2cm] (bl3) {Các tế bào được tách rời trong môi trường nuôi cây};
    \node [longblock,below of=bl3, node distance=2cm]
    (bl4) {Tế bào phân chia};
    \node [longblock, below of=bl4, node distance=1.75cm]
    (bl5) {Mô sẹo};
    \node [longblock, below of=bl5, node distance=1.75cm] (bl6) {Cây con sinh trưởng trong ống nghiệm};
    \node [longblock, below of=bl6, node distance=1.75cm] (bl7) {Đem trồng để tạo cây trưởng thành};

    \path [line] (bl1) -- (bl2);
    \path [line] (bl2) -- (bl3);
    \path [line] (bl3) -- (bl4);
    \path [line] (bl4) -- node[anchor=east] {Nuôi cấy} (bl5);
    \path [line] (bl5) -- node[anchor=east] {Nuôi cấy} node[anchor=west]{Hoocmôn sinh trưởng}(bl6);
    \path [line] (bl6) -- (bl7);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also it's recommended that you also include a screenshot of the current output, and also a sketch of what you want.

Comment: Also it might be better to use tcolorbox instead of TikZ e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552335/how-create-these-boxes-style

Comment: Actually also not that one (okay, reading the documentation (LaTeX2e unofficial reference manual) it's controlled by one of the `\...fraction` parameters), but still, if you only need the figures on the page then *you don't need that float environment*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put two figures in the same page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290186/how-to-put-two-figures-in-the-same-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I would put both images to one float with position options `[p]`. - Nesting `tikz` image in `tikz` image is not good idea, you can experiences unexpected problems (aligning of images)
- Defining new commands for inserting images doesn't shorten code or make it more clear, I would rather insert image directly in float environment
- Using additional `tikz` libraries can significant shorten code, make it more concise and clear:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Schola}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                chains,
                fit,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

%% tikz
\tikzset{FC/.style = {
node distance = 7mm,
  start chain = going below,
%
  base/.style = {draw, rounded corners, line width=0.5pt},
   FIT/.style = {base, fill=gray!10,
                 minimum width=\dimexpr\linewidth-1.2cm\relax,
                 inner sep=4mm,
                 xshift=\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-10em\relax, yshift=2mm,
                 fit=##1},
    T/.style = {base, fill=gray!30,
                anchor=west, xshift=5mm},
%
 line/.style = {draw, -Latex},
block/.style = {base, text width=5em, align=center},
longblock/.style = {base, fill=white,
                    text width=10em, align=center, minimum height=1cm},
height=1cm},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\small}
                }
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FC]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={longblock, on chain, join=by line}]
\node   (bl1) {Chọn vật liệu nuôi cấy};
\node   (bl2) {Khử trùng};
\node   (bl3) {Tạo chồi};
\node   (bl4) {Tạo rễ};
\node   (bl5) {Cấy cây vào môi trường thích ứng};
\node   (bl6) {Trồng cây trong vườn ươm};
    \end{scope}
\scoped[on background layer] 
\node[FIT=(bl1) (bl6)] (big) {};
\node[T] (small) at (big.north west) {QT nhân giống bằng nuôi cấy mô};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\medskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FC]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={longblock, on chain, join=by line}]
\node   (bl1) {Lát cắt ngang củ cà rốt};
\node   (bl2) {Các mẫu mô};
\node   (bl3) {Các tế bào được tách rời trong môi trường nuôi cây};
\node   (bl4) {Tế bào phân chia};
\node   (bl5) {Mô sẹo};
\node   (bl6) {Cây con sinh trưởng trong ống nghiệm};
\node   (bl7) {Đem trồng để tạo cây trưởng thành};
    \end{scope}
\scoped[on background layer]
\node[FIT=(bl1) (bl7)] (big) {};
\node[T] (small) at (big.north west) {Nhân giống bằng nuôi cấy mô ở cà rốt};
% 
\path   (bl4) edge["Nuôi cấy"] (bl5);
\path   (bl5) edge["Nuôi cấy" ', 
                   "Hoocmôn sinh trưởng"]   (bl6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
For the flowchart asked in your comment:

- please always put your ask in question, that it can be (better) visible to all site members
- you can draw this flowchart on the same way as are drawn in above MWE, so its code can be:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FC] 
    \begin{scope}[nodes={block, on chain, join=by line}]
\node (bl1) {Hạt giống SNC}; 
\node (bl2) {Hạt giống \\ NC}; 
\node (bl3) {Hạt giống XN}; 
    \end{scope}
\node [below right = of bl3] (bl4) {Sản xuất đại trà}; 
\path [line] (bl3) |- (bl4); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

however, your document preamble had to have the content of above MWE's preamble too.

[image]

Comment: @Anon, on the same way as is done in my answer.  See addendum.

Comment: What code do you use to make the light grey portion covering the flowchart smaller?

Comment: @Anon, all used code is in the answer. All modes size are the same as you defined in your MWE.  Defined are as part of  nodes styles collected in `\tikzset`.