# How can I create colored boxes / containers?

Tags: tcolorbox

**Self-answered and possibly duplicate. Please see first answer <3**

title is so freaking dumb that please someone fix or suggest me an alternative title.

What I want is basically this:

[image]

With https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox I only managed to achieve one singular box that I could split in half with horizontally but that is it. I can't replicate a color box like this, even a black/white one. I don't know if I understand this correctly:

[image]

If yes or not, how can I make a layout like this?

My furthest attempt:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{bookmark}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{theorem}[1]{
    title={\textbf{Theorem~\thetcbcounter: #1}},
    bookmark={#1}
}


\begin{document}
\section{example box}
\begin{theorem}{example theorem}
  \lipsum[1]
  \tcbsubtitle{example theorem cont.}
  \lipsum[2]

\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

which is. literally nothing.

[image]

which summarizes my latex skills. help :(

*This is not for commercial or any serious book writing I just want my notes look kinda shiny.*

Comment: my mspaint skills are unmatchable

Comment: Do you have any code as a starting point?

Comment: Sure! It is very plain but let me add it.

Comment: @PaulA I dont know if this will even help, but here you go. Edited main post.

Comment: A good place to start could be. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451457/create-page-layout-with-beautiful-boxes-tcolorbox

Comment: Why don't you just use a description list for the stuff inside. E.g. `\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{problem}{description}{1}
\setlist*[problem]{leftmargin=2.5cm,labelwidth=!}`

Comment: Yep! I also added that link as self answer.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be duplicate of [How create these boxes style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552335/how-create-these-boxes-style), already provides a customizable entrypoint for my problem. Thank you all anyways!