# Yellow colored LaTeX boxes

Tags: color, boxes, fancybox

Can someone tell me how to replicate this style of boxes in LaTeX, that is, to make a box of that color and style? I do not want the Remark command too. I just want a code that makes a box of that color and style, maybe change the background color of the text to lighter yellow. Thank you. You may or may not add the same text given in the below prototype

[image]

Comment: See the tcolobox package

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512504/134144 might be interesting. Other answers also include some interesting alternatives depending on the contents of your box.