# How to highlight quoted section?

Tags: color

I have tried to highlight a quoted section in my document using `\colorbox{}{}`, but when I put in there a large section it doesn't fit in my page anymore.

```
\colorbox{yellow}{
Quote from very very very very loooooooooongs section:
The properties of depth-first search depend strongly on whether the 
}
```

The output I want to get is something like this:

> Quote from very very very very loooooooooongs section: 
>       The properties of depth-first search depend strongly on whether the

Comment: You might want to look at the package tcolorbox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the simplest, most canonical way to change the background color of quoted text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435630/what-is-the-simplest-most-canonical-way-to-change-the-background-color-of-quote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `\colorbox` creates a one-line box that is wide enough to contain all of the text given as argument. If this text is longer than one line, the `\colorbox` will be too long for the line and reach into the margins. Also, because `\colorbox` is one-line only, you cannot use `\\` inside.

One way to overcome this is to put the text that you want to highlight into a `\parbox`. A `\parbox` creates a box of specified width and breaks the lines inside to match this width. In this example, I create a `\parbox` of width `\textwidth-2\fboxsep`, where `\fboxsep` is the inner margin left free to the left and right of a colorbox. Thus, this box fits exactly inside the page margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{yellow}{
Quote from very very very very loooooooooongs section:
The properties of depth-first search depend strongly on whether the 
}

\colorbox{yellow}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{
Quote from very very very very loooooooooongs section:\\
The properties of depth-first search depend strongly on whether the 
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

However, it is probably easier to use the powerful `tcolorbox` package to achieve the same thing. Here is an example where I define an environment `mybox` resulting in the same output as above, but with an easier user interface.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=yellow,boxsep=0pt,left=\fboxsep,right=\fboxsep,top=\fboxsep,bottom=\fboxsep,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
Quote from very very very very loooooooooongs section:
The properties of depth-first search depend strongly on whether the 
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it makes sense now