# How to define an environment with appointed color background?

Tags: color, environments

I want to define an environment with appointed color, that is to say the whole environment from the `\begin{env}` to `\end{env}` will be drawed by the color. Just like a code block. Roughly, this is waht I expect.

[image]

I tried to use `\colorbox`, but it seemed that the box didn't support for multiple lines of text. For instance, I have a costomized environment `myenv`, then how can I realize what I expect.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
    %\colorbox{gray}
    \medskip
    \begin{quote}
        \centering
}{\end{quote}\medskip}

\begin{document}
    \section{A}
    \lipsum{1}
    \begin{myenv}
        \lipsum{2}
    \end{myenv}
    \lipsum{3}\par
    {\centering
    \colorbox{gray}{AAAAAA}
\end{document}
```

Please give me an example. Thanks.

Comment: See the `tcolorbox` package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the simplest, most canonical way to change the background color of quoted text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435630/what-is-the-simplest-most-canonical-way-to-change-the-background-color-of-quote)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stay with `framed.sty` package, then try with the below `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.5}%change what ever you like

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
    %\colorbox{gray}
    \medskip
    \begin{shaded*}
        \centering
}{\end{shaded*}\medskip}

\begin{document}
    \section{A}
    \lipsum{1}
    \begin{myenv}
        \lipsum{2}
    \end{myenv}
    \lipsum{3}\par
    {\centering
    \colorbox{gray}{AAAAAA}
\end{document}
```

Apart from this, `tcolorbox.sty` and `mdframed.sty` also having nice features...

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray, breakable, sharp corners]
    \medskip
    \begin{quote}
        \centering
}{\end{quote}\medskip\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}
    \section{A}
    \lipsum{1}
    \begin{myenv}
        \lipsum{2}
    \end{myenv}
    \lipsum{3}\par
    {\centering
    \colorbox{gray}{AAAAAA}
\end{document}
```

[image]