# How is this colored background text achieved?

Tags: color, tcolorbox

I saw the following beautifully colored text for definitions, theorems, examples... in someone's notes. How do we achieve this in latex?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a custom tcolorbox, see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) for more information and examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a box using the tcolorbox package or any other? (image)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512501/create-a-box-using-the-tcolorbox-package-or-any-other-image)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to reproduce the second image with `ntheorem, mdframed` and `xcolor`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}%
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
%\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[amsmath,framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[ntheorem]{mdframed}
\theoremheaderfont{\sffamily\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont\upshape}
   \theoremstyle{plain}
\newmdtheoremenv[topline=false, bottomline=false, rightline=false, leftline=true, linewidth=2pt, linecolor=Purple, backgroundcolor=Thistle! 20, innertopmargin=10pt, innerbottommargin=10pt]{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
The rule $1$ cannot follow. $1$ corresponds to
    \[ A = \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0
    \end{bmatrix} \]%
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox, xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!15, sharp corners, boxrule=0pt, leftrule=1mm, colframe=blue]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask why the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote but a possible explanation might be that the person that downvoted felt that it is a bad idea to answer a question that is a duplicate, because it causes fragmentation of answers to the same question in multiple places and/or because you don't 'deserve' reputation for providing essentially the same answer as has been given before.

Comment: I noticed that you wrote your answer before the first vote to close as duplicate so you cannot be 'accused' of knowingly answering a duplicate but maybe the downvoter felt that you should have looked for the duplicate yourself instead of answering.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391788/how-much-effort-are-answerers-expected-to-put-into-finding-duplicates and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376165/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-answerers for related discussions on Meta.SO and also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202895/should-we-downvote-answers-to-obvious-duplicate-questions from Meta.SE.