# How to change quote behavior?

Tags: preamble, renewcommand, quotation, org-mode

I'm using Org-Mode to write documents that I export to LaTeX. Org-Mode exports its quote blocks to:

```tex
\begin{quote}
...
\end{quote}
```

In order to color these quotes I'm using the following code (found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435630/what-is-the-simplest-most-canonical-way-to-change-the-background-color-of-quote)) in the preamble of some of my Org-Mode documents.

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{xcolor}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{framed}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{quoting}
#+LATEX_HEADER:  \colorlet{shadecolor}{grey}
#+LATEX_HEADER:\newenvironment{shadedquotation}
#+LATEX_HEADER: {\begin{shaded*}
#+LATEX_HEADER:  \quoting[leftmargin=0pt, vskip=0pt]}
#+LATEX_HEADER: {\endquoting
#+LATEX_HEADER: \end{shaded*}}
```

The issue that I have is that I have to replace `{quote}` by `{shadedquotation}` each time I do an export.

In order to avoid this, I thought of changing LaTeX `quote` behavior (so it would behave as `shadedquotation`) by adding some code in the preamble of the exported LaTeX document.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Isn't this more of a org-mode/emacs question then? You need a way to reconfigure org-mode such than when it handles quotes (blockquotes?) then it should use your custom env name. That hasn't much to do with LaTeX it self

Comment: No, the idea is not to change Emacs config, since I'd like the behavior change to be on LaTeX side. I tried to use \renewcommand but it didn't work (may be I don't know how to use it).

Comment: Said differently, I don't want quote to be replaced by shadedquotation, I'd like quote to behave like shaded quotation.

Comment: Then why are you defining `shadedquotation` in the first place? You could just redefine `quote`

Comment: That's what I wanted to do at first, but I didn't find how... I only found solutions where people created new commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `\newenvironment{shadedquotation}` by `\renewenvironment{quote}`:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{xcolor}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{framed}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{quoting}
#+LATEX_HEADER:  \colorlet{shadecolor}{grey}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewenvironment{quote}
#+LATEX_HEADER: {\begin{shaded*}
#+LATEX_HEADER:  \quoting[leftmargin=0pt, vskip=0pt]}
#+LATEX_HEADER: {\endquoting
#+LATEX_HEADER: \end{shaded*}}
```